# how to create horizontal text carousel

Tags: angularjs, carousel, angular-material

This question might seem silly question. But I'm really stuck with it.

I am trying to create a carousel with above center title and below centered Description text. There are lot of example on google but I couldn't find anything appropriate.

1. I am using `angular-material` and there is no carousel implemented in `angular-material` till now.
2. there is awesome carousel in `materializecss` but when I am adding materialize in project lot of element CSS conflicting because of angular-material and materializecss.
3. then I decided to use some other directives like JK carousel it is not allowing me create text on image.
4. there is carousel in `ui.bootstrap` it also getting conflict with drop downs component.

Could anyone please tell me how can I achieve my requirement?
I have to use `angular-material`, there's no other choice. So any help using angular-material will be a great support.

Comment: Perhaps this will help? - https://codepen.io/Fabiano/pen/LACzk - uses ui.bootstrap but maybe you can play with CSS?

Comment: I have gone through this It uses ui.bootstrap as I have mention above in question it will create conflict in css of drop downs.

Comment: Yes I understand, do you have an plunker or jsfiddle I could have a look at?

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using [angular 3d carousel](https://github.com/Wlada/angular-carousel-3d) in my angular-material project.  It has [html](http://vladimirbujanovic.com/angular-carousel-3d/demo/demo.html) slide version. You can build all your angular material classes in that slide html.

```
<carousel3d-slide ng-repeat="slide in app.slides2 track by $index" ng-style="{'background': slide.bg}">
    <div style="padding: 20px; color: #fff">
        <md-card md-theme="{{ showDarkTheme ? 'dark-grey' : 'default' }}" md-theme-watch>
            <md-card-title>
                <md-card-title-text>
                    <span class="md-headline">Card with image</span>
                    <span class="md-subhead">Large</span>
                </md-card-title-text>
                <md-card-title-media>
                    <div class="md-media-lg card-media"></div>
                </md-card-title-media>
            </md-card-title>
            <md-card-actions layout="row" layout-align="end center">
                <md-button>Action 1</md-button>
                <md-button>Action 2</md-button>
            </md-card-actions>
        </md-card>
    </div>
</carousel3d-slide>
```

Comment: this is great for AngularJS, is there an Angular variant of this?